# Crawl coverage and Page rank effect if few website pages has broken links

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, pagerank, search-results

We have millions of pages in our website and most of the pages have indexed by Google.

Few days before we generated few pages which have few broken links (showing 404 pages). For example, if page has 20 -50 links then one or two links are broken.

Does this effect the rank of the page and search results?

Few pages which have broken links are not visible to users, (I can see the links by only checking the view source of the page) but they are getting crawled by google on daily basis.

Comment: I do not need to tell you that broken links goes to content quality and possibly freshness if a link is not fixed for a while. No-one from Google is going to show-up at your door with a mob hit-man for broken links, however, you should want to fix this in a reasonable manner. In other words, fix them as quickly as you can it and do not worry about it. But definitely do not leave them or accept them as a part of your business.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: if you are getting good links to a 404’d page, you should 301 redirect it to the page the link was supposed to go to, or if that page has been removed then to a similar or parent page. You do not have to 301 redirect all 404 pages. This can in fact slow down your site if you have way too many redirects. If you have an old page or a large set of pages that you want completely erased, it is ok to let these 404. It is actually the Google recommended way to let the Googlebot know which pages you do not want anymore.

[image]